# Instantiate a hashmap by a specified object

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I want to make a constructor for a class called `Manager` which takes as argument `Object`:

```
public class Manager{
    public Manager(Object object){}
}
```

In this constructor i want to instantiate a non-local HashMap object that uses `String`  and the constructor parameter `object`, so it will be something like that:

```
public class Manager{
    private HashMap objects;
    public Manager(Object object){
        objects = new HashMap<String, object>(); /*note it's 'object' and not 'Object'*/
    }
}
```

So that if from example i will instantiate a manager i will be able to do something like this:

```
Manager myObjectManager = new Manager(MyObject); /* Create a new Manager instance with MyObject object for an example */
myObjectManager.getDescription(); /* Use a method from the MyObject class
```

I know the examples i provided are not using a right syntax of java, i have only used java to describe what i'm looking for.

What i'm just trying to explain is that i want a  constructor that could instantiate a HashMap object by using the constructor parameters.

**edit**: i'll try to explain better, the manager class is supposed to hold objects from the same class and use the string to find them. for an example i'll use a spritesheet manager which i'll use to find a spritesheet of the player.

Comment: What is the ``String`` you use as a key in your map?

Comment: It's just an id, so you could access objects by its name.

Comment: What is `MyObject`? What other objects can you pass in constructor? Is there any hierarchical relationship between those objects?

Comment: "new HashMap<String, object>();" object needs to be a type. You put a concrete object into the type definition. I suggest to give a better example what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Timo I want to achieve a hashmap which i can choose it's types by a constructor.

Comment: I see. See below, the keyword you should looking for is "Generic types"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up the type of an instance and the instance itself!

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe generics might be a solution:

```
public class Manager<T> {
    private final Map<String, T> objects;

    public Manager() {
        objects = new HashMap<String, T>();
    }
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
Manager<MyObject> myManager = new Manager<MyObject>();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there:

```
public class Manager<T> {

    private final Map<String, T> myMap;

    public Manager(){
        myMap = new HashMap<String, T>();
    }
}
```

So you declare `Manager` as a generic class with type parameter `T`, you can then use this parameter in the `Map`. Instantiation of `Manager` would look like:

```
final Manager<MyObject> manager = new Manager<MyObject>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you could use Generics to solve it as:

```
class Manager<T> {
    HashMap<String, T> map = new HashMap<String, T>();;
    public Manager(T object) {
        map.put("something", object); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HashMap declaration like.

```
public Manager(Object object){
        objects = new HashMap<String, object>();
}
```

is **not possible** in Java. Becasue, object should be only non primitive type, not any reference of object.

Comment: "I know the examples i provided are not using a right syntax of java, i have only used java to describe what i'm looking for."